# XamlParseException when adding code behind to Silverlight ResourceDictionary

Tags: silverlight, code-behind, resourcedictionary, xamlparseexception

When I execute my Silverlight application with code behind for my ResourceDictionary  I get this expception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred.
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' [Line: 9 Position:35]
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at MyApp.Silverlight.App.InitializeComponent()
at MyApp.Silverlight.App..ctor()
```

StyleResources.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="MyApp.Silverlight.StyleResources"
    x:ClassModifier="public">
```

StyleResources.xaml.cs:

```
namespace MyApp.Silverlight
{
    public partial class StyleResources : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public StyleResources()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

As seen from other stackoverflow post this is how I included the ResourceDictionary into my MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:basics="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls" 
    x:Class="MyApp.Silverlight.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="944" d:DesignHeight="592"
    xmlns:resource="clr-namespace:MyApp.Silverlight;assembly=MyApp.Silverlight"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="resourcestyles">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <resource:StyleResources />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Can anyone tell me whats going wrong here?

Comment: This feels plain wrong, and for starters, you didn't define which dictionary StyleResources points at.

Comment: What do you mean with "you didn't define which dictionary StyleResources points at"? `<resource:StyleResources />` ?

Comment: Simply inheriting from ResourceDictionary is not enough information to load the specific resource dictionary you want. Imagine you had 10 of those!

Comment: On which file is the error raised on? What happens at line 9 of that file? Which SO post are you referring to? did you thoroughly follow the instructions there? What is it you really wish to accomplish by adding code-behind to a resource dictionary?

Comment: Argh, I just found out that there was another ResourceDictionary entry in the App.xaml.cs. I've no idea why because I've never touched that file  but now everything is working. Shame on me...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <ResourceDictionary x:Key="resourcestyles">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StyleResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
```